# Typesetting MAGMA code with minted?

Tags: minted, code

I enjoy highlighting my Python code with minted. However I now would like to do the same with my Magma code (Magma is a commercial computer algebra system of broadly similar scope as GAP).

However minted does not recognise Magma out-of-the-box and so I am enquiring if anyone has written the relevant lexer (I think that is the name of what is required.)

Google provides nothing relevant in response to my trying a few keyword combinations.

Any advice, information or alternatives gratefully received.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/extra/highlight/README.txt) minted is not supported, but you can use [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) instead.

Comment: magma is [not listed by pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/?highlight=gap#lexers-for-computer-algebra-systems) but if you find a similar language and know some python, [modifying the lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/) may not be so hard, you can specify custom lexers to pygmentize via minted.

Comment: The last line of the documentation @DG' posted states "Syntax highlighting for *pygments* and *Sphinx* is in preparation." Maybe; if you nudge them a little, they'll finish it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions; I will try them and see which works best.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/magma-minted/hjzwcfgznqmr

Answer (score 0):

One can use LaTeX `listings` package instead.

Download `lstlang0.sty` from https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/extra/ and put it in your workspace. Don't forget to type `\usepackage{listings}` and `\usepackage{lstlang0}`.

And one can put code here

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Magma] CODE HERE \end{lstlisting}
```